# Scrollable region with scroll pane but not scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, scrollbar

I was viewing some Facebook photos. I observed this thing, when you click on an image, it opens as a modal overlay. The background is still hazily visible, the scroll pane is still there, but the scroll bar just disappears. Can anyone tell me how to do it? I mean, setting body's overflow to hidden will make the entire scroll pane disappear. Here the scrollpane is there, but the scrollbar is not..

Comment: A native browser scrollpane with no scrollbar obviously means the element for which the scrollpane is displayed has a content height that matches the element height.

Comment: Umm, I didn't quite get that. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can force a scrollpane to be displayed with `overflow:scroll`. If the elements content are not larger then the elements height – then there is no scrollbar to display.

Comment: But the actual HTML page (which is quite long and thus has scrollbars appearing) is still there, all I am doing is placing another `div` on top of it. How can that affect the scroll? I am trying it out with jQuery-UI dialog..Can you give a demo, so that I can understand your point better?

Comment: If you want to figure out what element gets displayed how, use Firebug or something and have a look around …

Comment: I did. `body` still showed an `overflow` of `scroll`..

Comment: Of course, otherwise there would be no scrollpane (unless they gave it to another element). It’s just a matter of limiting the size of the rest of the content, so that the height of `body` does not exceed the screen height. If everything else that is displayed is in its own container, then setting that to screen height and `overflow:hidden` should work …

Comment: Okay, will try it and let you know..

Comment: So just let me see whether I have got it. Say the entire body's contents are wrapped in a parent container, with say, `id` **bodywrapper**. So before displaying the modal, I will set that container's height (not the body's) to screen height..Is that all?

Comment: Hi CBroe, it's working, except for a small glitch. If you note what FB does, you will see that if you minimize the browser to some lesser height and width than the full one, & click an image, it still opens the modal, but now scroll bars appear for both horizontal & vertical directions. These disappear when you again resize it to maximum, suggesting that it always sets the container's height to the maximum possible viewport's height. How do I get that? `$(window).height()` will change if you resize the window. Initial viewport height ain't reliable, since you may load the page while minimized.

Answer (score 0):

i think what youre looking for is the osx-like scrollbar that fades out when not being used.

see [Lion-like scrollbar with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863748/lion-like-scrollbar-with-jquery)

Comment: No, not really. Here the scrollbar doesn't show at all..And I am talking of the default browser scrollbar, not any custom made scrollbar.