# Scrollbar Appear on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I saw a site recently that had a hidden scrollbar which appear on scroll. This may also be because it's a slickgrid. I'm able to control my scrollbar CSS specific to a `div` but can't control it from javascript. My script so far has been pretty simplistic:

```
$('#mydiv').scroll(function(){
    $('#mydiv::-webkit-scrollbar').fadeIn(500);
    //I've also tried .css() above and tried the .hover event as well
})
```

My div and scrollbar css:

```
#mydiv{overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto; height: 80%; width: 100%;}
#mydiv::-webkit-scrollbar{display: none;}
```

Is there a way to show the scrollbar on scroll? I already know how to control on hover by changing overflow on `:hover` in css.

Comment: See: [Lion-like scrollbar with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863748/lion-like-scrollbar-with-jquery) (My answer is the accepted one.)

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look and remove if it answers my question

Answer (score 1):

No plugins needed, try this:

JS:

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
  var el = $('body');
  el.css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
  if (el[0].hideScroll) clearTimeout(el[0].hideScroll);
  el[0].hideScroll = setTimeout(function() {
    el.css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
  }, 500);
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: hmm this didn't work for me. doesn't give me any errors in console either.

Comment: @Zack it appears to be working for me. Check it out on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhyyhnag/). Make sure you are using jQuery

Comment: well, +1 for no plugin. I'm too far into my project to figure out what's wrong with my CSS, it hasn't worked for me but I'll look at it when I have time!